# How do I move to the next item in a list using loops?

Tags: python

I need to create a subroutine in python which identifies the highest number in a list, but I don't know how to move to the next item in the list using a loop

I've tried to add 1 to the counter, but I am not entirely sure of the of the syntax

```
number = []
for i in range(0, 5): # set up loop to run 5 times
    numbers = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
    number.append(numbers) # append to our_list
tempmax = number[0]
maximum = 0
for i in number:
    if tempmax > maximum:
        maximum = tempmax
        tempmax = number[+1]
    else:
        tempmax = number[+1]

print(maximum)
```

This is what I've tried, but I don't really know how to fix it. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: use `i=0 tempmax=number[i] i+=1`, use a additional varible `i` and then increment it

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for `max(numbers)`?

Comment: You need to read the documentation for [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Answer (score 1):

A [for loop](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) will give you each item in the sequence you are iterating over.

You named the input number `numbers` and your list of numbers `number`. Swap those names around to be clearer.

You are iterating over a list of `numbers` so each item is a `number`. You named it `i` which probably made you think it was an index, but it's not, it's the actual number. Give it a good name:

```
for number in numbers:
```

Then you want to test whether the number is the maximum:

```
    if number > maximum:
        maximum = number
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this want you to want to do?

```
number = []
for i in range(0, 5): # set up loop to run 5 times
    numbers = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
    number.append(numbers) # append to our_list
tempmax = number[0]
maximum = 0
for i in range(len(number)-1):
    if tempmax > maximum:
        maximum = tempmax
        tempmax = number[i+1]
    else:
        tempmax = number[i+1]

print(maximum)
```

If you want to determine maximum value in a list, you can also do something much easier like this (without having to recreate the wheel).

```
max_val = max(number)
print(max_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the for loop seeks the next item automatically and loads it in the variable you asked it to... `for YOUR_VAR in YOUR_ITERABLE`, you either need to work on the **items** you want, or on the **indexes**.

So, if your items were `arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`, you could access them both ways.

```
for item in arr:
     print(item) # Will print successively 10, then 20, then 30, then 40, then 50.

array_indices = len(arr)
for index in array_indices:
    print(index) # will print successively 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    print(arr[index]) # will print successively 10, then 20... 30, 40, 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are looking for `max(numbers)`. It will return the biggest number in the list.

If you want to get index of the number after maximum, try `numbers.index(max(numbers)) + 1`

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
>>> max(a)
4
>>> a.index(max(a))
3
>>> a[a.index(max(a)) + 1]
1
```

Note: list.index() return index of the first maximum.